# Unable to display data in react bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to display data filed using this code.

Here I'm setting the user set:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/local/organization/user')
    .then(response => {
      // console.log(response.data.data.user[0].name)
      this.setState({ users: response.data.data })   
    })
}
```

Here is the React bootstrap table code. It's iterating but data fields are not displayed.

```
<BootstrapTable
  data={this.state.users}
  remote={true}
  striped
  hover
  pagination
  options={options}
>
  <TableHeaderColumn width="150" isKey dataField="data.user_id">
    ID
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn
    width="150"
    dataField="name"
    filter={{ type: "TextFilter", delay: 1000 }}
  >
    Name
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn width="150" dataField="email">
    Email
  </TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

Comment: nothing displayed? can you show the data of `this.state.users`?

Comment: {
    "data": [
        {
            "user": {
                "address": "bhiwandi",
                "blood_group": "B+",
                "city": "1",
            }
        }
    "error": false,
    "message": "list of user"
}

Comment: but this data don't contain key `name` and `email`, table will display the data when it will find those keys in each object of the array.

Comment: @MayankShukla if possible look into to this.. even city and blood_grp also not display